# Matplotlib: Gridspec and aspect='auto' not compatible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want 4 exactly squared subplots contained within a square figure

I have the following minimal code which is unable to produce what I want.

```
#latexify()

g1 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2,height_ratios=[1,1],width_ratios=[1,1])

g1.update(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.4) # set the spacing between axes

f, ((ax0, ax1), (ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')

ax0 = subplot(g1[0])
ax1 = subplot(g1[1])
ax2 = subplot(g1[2])
ax3 = subplot(g1[3])

ax0.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
ax2.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
ax3.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

ax0.set_title("G/G")
ax1.set_title("G/BN")
ax2.set_title("BN/BN (0$\degree$)")
ax3.set_title("BN/BN (60$\degree$)")

ax0.set_xticklabels([])
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
ax1.set_yticklabels([])
ax3.set_yticklabels([])

ax0.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax1.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax2.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax3.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
```

[image: Toy plot]

I get a lot of white space between the left and right subplots. I tried several options from other questions: turn of sharex/sharey, forcing different figure sizes (that's what the commented-out latexify() function allows me to do), play with the gridspec heigh_ratios, but to no avail.

Comment: maybe this is of interest for you: when doing plots like this I like to put everything into for loops for making changes easier.
`for ax in ax0,ax1,ax2,ax3:
    ax.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')`
and all the other stuff that repeats itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the figure size so that it's actually square.

```
f.set_size_inches((5,5))
```

[image]

Alternately, you can specify the `figsize` option in your `subplots` call

```
f, ((ax0, ax1), (ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', 
                                           sharey='row', figsize=(5,5))
```

Comment: This works. The problem lied in the way I was using my latexify() command. Height and width are not independent variables there. I've tweaked this now. I'll accept this answer as it correctly solves the problem it was presented here. Thank you!